# How do I successfully convert an image to text in php using the Tesseract libraries`

Tags: php, tesseract

I read through the guide on github(https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php), and installed TesseractOCR v4.00 both in my localdisk and the htdocs of xampp. I also downloaded the zip folder and extracted it in my htdocs, yet I do not get the output that is shown on github. Below is the code I tried.

```
<?php
    require "src/TesseractOCR.php";
    echo (new TesseractOCR('text.jpg'))->run();
?>
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: What is the output that you get?

Comment: It actually did not display anything, just a blank page. I just realized that I probably have to use the command line to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

First Install it with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

create a dir called `composer` in your xampp project folder than create a file inside it named `composer.json` with the following code

```
{
    "require": {
        "thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr": "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

than go to your composer dir by **cmd** with the comands `cd /composer/dir` 
than inside it run the command `composer install`
for you understand hot to run it see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ejr4Xqs9V2I
than do it i your php file

```
<?php
include_once("composer/vendor/autoload.php");
echo (new TesseractOCR('text.jpg'))->run();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, when I try to display the output on a page It comes out blank, but I'm guessing that's cause I probably have to use the command line to see the output. Thanks though, at least I now know how to use composer.

Comment: you are welcome, if my answer solved your problem please mark as right

Comment: I did, my reputation just isn't high enough for it to show

Comment: I will give you a upvote so you will win more reputation and be able to accept the answer